# When I start a new session, the value are set, but then in next page I cannot 'see' them

Tags: php, session-cookies

I am pretty new to PHP, and I am exploring how to use sessions in PHP. Now, I have created 2 very simple php pages:

session_start.php:

```php
<?php
session_start();
echo 'Welcome to page #1';

$_SESSION['favcolor'] = 'green';
$_SESSION['animal']   = 'cat';
$_SESSION['time']     = time();

// Works if session cookie was accepted
echo '<br /><a href="session_start2.php">page 2</a>';
// Print session variables to check if session started

echo $_SESSION['favcolor'] = 'green';
echo $_SESSION['animal']   = 'cat';
echo $_SESSION['time']     = time();
```

session_start2.php:

```php
<?php
session_start();
echo 'Welcome to page #2<br />';

echo $_SESSION['favcolor']; // green
echo $_SESSION['animal'];   // cat
echo date('Y m d H:i:s', $_SESSION['time']);
```

while I see in the first script the $_SESSION values, when I click on second, I don't see anything...
I am uploading the scripts on the server, so I am not working locally on my laptop.

thanks in advance for your support

Comment: FYI: `echo $_SESSION['favcolor'] = 'green';` is **assignment**, not comparision so these 3 last lines in 1st script make no much sense.

Comment: On top of that^. If you still have issues: check in your browser if your session id is saved in a session cookie under the name `PHPSESSID` (or different if you changed PHP settings (https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.name)

Comment: Also, make 100% sure there's not space or any blank character before `<?php` (if it was, it would make PHP to output content after which setting any headers (including session id) would not be possible.

Comment: Why don't try to pass your data to the second page by using `$_get['data']` ?

Comment: after updating ph to version 74 it works fine.
Thank you!